# how to query using sql server management studio(ssms) for all changes done on the database

Tags: sql-server

I want to query for all changes done on the database using ssms, such that i will get type of transaction executed, user who did the change, date, fields of the table that were changed. My database run on sql server.

This for a digital forensic on a database that some employee change.
 i have try a few option but none is helpful. e.g

```
select * from sys.objects
where type = 'U' or type = 'P'
and modify_date between '2016-12-01' and '2018-12-31'
```

This is not giving me what i want.

I expect the result have type of transaction executed, user who did the change, date, fields of the table that were changed.

Comment: You won't be able to access this information unless you do some preparations **beforehand** on each database/instance, such as setting triggers or extended events to track all this. Also, "all changes done" might be an overkill, you will be storing a really huge amount of data, you should focus on what you want to see only.

Comment: This isn't something that can easily be set up my someone at entry level either i'm afraid (considering your question, I'm assuming you are). If this is something you need to set up, I would suggeet talking to your DBA first, to ensure you aren't going to be impacting the server performance wise and then talking to those in your business more experienced with the product to guide you through.

Comment: thanks for the response but am working on a backup so performance is not an issue. the live db is run on a difference computer